# What happens if we feed rule based labels, to train a Neural Network?

Tags: algorithm, neural-network, deep-learning

I don't have hand labeled data right now, but a data in which labels are created by some rule based algorithm using other features. Can I train my Neural Network with this data? 
if it gives a good score, can I use the same algorithm to train with hand-labeled data? would it give similar accuracy?

Comment: If your rule-based algorithm gives good results, why do you want to use a neural network?

Comment: I don't trust the result by rule based algorithm, hence Neural Network. but to train, I don't have the hand-labelled data right now. so, in order to build an algorithm and test them, can I use the label by rule based algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't realize it, but you've already answered your own question: "I don't trust the result by rule based algorithm".  Now think back to the *purpose* of a label: it's your **ground truth** for training.  If you do not trust those results, then those results *cannot* be any sort of ground truth for you.

The training results of your neural network would be based entirely on the rule-based labels.  The NN operation would, at best, reproduce the results you don't trust.  There is no way it will serve as an independent check on the rule-based system.

---

However, you can certainly *develop* your neural network with that data and learn something about the viability of the model topology.  If your goal is to have a viable NN that will be ready once you *do* have hand-labeled data, then you're very much on the right track for methodology.

Do not put much faith in getting a "good score" from the rule-based data; your purpose is to build a model that will give a good score with the hand-labeled data.  The preliminary result's accuracy is self-referential, and is no better than the quality of the input data.